# Programmatically mounting a FAT32 filesystem with UTF8

Tags: c++, linux

How can I mount a FAT/FAT32 device using "mount()" function (from "mount.h", see "man 2 mount") in a way that it will be mounted UTF8?

This is the relevant code I use to mount it 'til now:

```
mount_result = mount(device_node, device_mount_point, fstype, MS_NOATIME, "");
```

Thanks,
Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to the mount command is a string interpreted by the file system driver in the kernel. It is the same you would pass to the mount shell command. For UTF8 I believe the string should be:

```
mount_result = mount(device_node, device_mount_point, fstype, MS_NOATIME, "iocharset=utf8");
```

Comment: If the manpage is to be trusted, `iocharset` is not amongst the options for `vfat`. You may be thinking of `ntfs` (where it is deprecated anyway). `utf8` looks like the correct argument.

Comment: The correct answer is passing "iocharset=utf8". Tested it on a 2.6.33.2 kernel, mount from util-linux-ng 2.15.1 (with libblkid support). Man pages may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount):

> The data argument is interpreted by the different file systems. Typically it is a string of comma-separated options understood by this file system.

And from the manpage of [mount(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount), "Mount options for vfat":

> utf8 : 
>   UTF8 is the filesystem safe 8-bit encoding of Unicode that is used by the console. It can be be enabled for the filesystem with this option. If 'uni_xlate' gets set, UTF8 gets disabled.

Therefore, this should give you the desired behavior:

```
mount_result = mount(device_node, device_mount_point, fstype, MS_NOATIME, "utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to try "utf8=1".

Comment: Hi BeeBand, I hope you read this message. This comment is not abouyt this answer. I know I am breaking SO rules, but I just wanted to talk to you after I read this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/197675/is-there-any-way-to-get-faster-at-solving-bugs-ive-just-had-a-warning-from-my?lq=1 question of yours. I was extremely saddened to read that you lost your job. Then I looked at your SO profile that you haven't had any activity since Sept. 2013 (which was a few months after you posted that question.). I am sorry for stalking you like this, but I was very curious ... (cont)

Comment: to know what happened with you. It has been almost 2 years since that terrible thing happened to you. Are you doing fine now? Did you get another job? I really hope you are doing better now. I hope you came through stronger. 
And I do hope you take some time to reply to my curiosity if it is not too much!